In performing an update on F-41, the following conflicts from the repositories were reported. What steps can I take to resolve them...if any?
[quote]
Problem 1: installed package libcurl-minimal-8.9.1-2.fc41.x86_64 conflicts with libcurl(x86-64) provided by libcurl-8.9.1-2.fc41.x86_64 from fedora

package dnf5-plugin-automatic-5.2.6.2-1.fc41.x86_64 from fedora requires libcurl-full(x86-64), but none of the providers can be installed
cannot install the best update candidate for package libcurl-minimal-8.9.1-2.fc41.x86_64
cannot install the best update candidate for package dnf-automatic-4.21.1-1.fc41.noarch
Problem 2: problem with installed package
installed package libcurl-minimal-8.9.1-2.fc41.x86_64 conflicts with libcurl(x86-64) provided by libcurl-8.9.1-2.fc41.x86_64 from fedora
package libcurl-minimal-8.9.1-2.fc41.x86_64 from fedora conflicts with libcurl(x86-64) provided by libcurl-8.9.1-2.fc41.x86_64 from fedora
package dnf5-plugin-automatic-5.2.6.2-1.fc41.x86_64 from fedora requires libcurl-full(x86-64), but none of the providers can be installed
problem with installed package
installed package dnf-automatic-4.21.1-1.fc41.noarch requires python3-dnf = 4.21.1-1.fc41, but none of the providers can be installed
package dnf-automatic-4.21.1-1.fc41.noarch from fedora requires python3-dnf = 4.21.1-1.fc41, but none of the providers can be installed
cannot install both python3-dnf-4.21.1-2.fc41.noarch from updates and python3-dnf-4.21.1-1.fc41.noarch from @System
cannot install both python3-dnf-4.21.1-2.fc41.noarch from updates and python3-dnf-4.21.1-1.fc41.noarch from fedora
cannot install the best update candidate for package python3-dnf-4.21.1-1.fc41.noarch
[end quote]

I searched the

Ok. The issue with the repositories was resolved by Dnfdragora. I set the program on "To Update" and two selections were identified: update of Python3 and libcurl-minimal. The first was updated and the second removed from the system. I performed a CLI dnf-update check which showed no further conflicts. Hope this helps others.
